# Converting a string to double in Dart using double.parse()

Tags: google-api, dart, flutter

I am trying to convert coordinates returned from the Google Geo. API into doubles.  A simplified part of the response that gets returned is...

```
{ 
  locationData: {
    bounds: {
      northeast: 40.222222,
      southwest: 38.265987
    }
  }
}
```

When I use `print(locationData['bounds']['northeast'])` my console reads that and understands that the value is `40.222222` However, when I try to use a parse method, I get the following error:

`var neLat = double.parse(locationData['bounds']['northeast']);`

> I/flutter (10537): type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast where
>
> I/flutter (10537):   double is from dart:core
>
> I/flutter (10537):   String is from dart:core

That error leads me to believe that my parse is not valid, even though it is clearly a double value, just as a string.  Am I missing something for this conversion?  I have seen conversion in multiple examples using double.parse, I just can't figure out what my issue is..

Comment: If you parsed that map from JSON, the value is already a double.  The type error comes from passing a double to the parse method, which expects a string

Comment: @JonahWilliams oh you're right.. I am used to using TypeScript and having to declare the type, great to know it assumes the type.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value was parsed from JSON, Dart knows the value is a double and the error is telling me that the value is of type double and the convert expected type string.

So the error is much more clear once I understood!

Comment: So how to solve this? I am using dart, I parse a double from JSON and sigh it into a string like: "${this.myDoubleValue}" but got that error.

Comment: @NicholasJela  My problem was that I was trying to convert using `double.parse` on my value, but Dart had already coverted my JSON into a double, so it was trying to parse a double into a double, which is what was throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was too facing same issue.
I know it is a silly answer but it worked for me. I was using Getx to save states and while converting string to double it was displaying error

> String is not subtype of type double

as the state of previous variables was being saved, so I restarted the app and tried type casting and it worked well.